# What should be the topic in the mqtt where the commands are received in the fiware-orion?

Tags: mqtt, fiware, fiware-orion

I have been trying  to simulate a device communicating with the MQTT protocol, when I send the command to the orion from postman

```json
{
   "on":{
      "type":"command",
      "value":""
   }
}
```

I create this service

```json
{
   "services":[
      {
         "apikey":"4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
         "cbroker":"http://orion:1026",
         "entity_type":"IoT-PublicServices",
         "resource":""
      }
   ]
}
```

I suscribe to this topic  '/+/streetLight001/cmd', i use the wildcard '+', In the place of the '+' it is supposed to be the apikey but it does not work, could someone tell me what could be wrong?

[image: Mosquitto]

Comment: Please add the `-v` (verbose) option to the `mqtt-client sub` command (that way it will output the topic the message is received on as well as the message itself).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://fiware-iotagent-json.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usermanual.html#mqtt-binding) MQTT commands are sent to the following MQTT topic when using an MQTT binding: `/<apiKey>/<deviceId>/cmd`

Note Measures and commands are sent over different MQTT topics:

- Measures are sent northbound on the `/<protocol>/<api-key>/<device-id>/attrs` topic,
- Commands are sent southbound on the `/<api-key>/<device-id>/cmd` topic

The reasoning behind this is that when sending measures northbound from device to IoT Agent, it is necessary to explicitly identify which IoT Agent is needed to parse the data. This is done by prefixing the relevant MQTT topic with a protocol, otherwise there is no way to define which agent is processing the measure. This mechanism allows smart systems to connect different devices to different IoT Agents according to need.

For southbound commands, this distinction is unnecessary since the correct IoT Agent has already registered itself for the command during the device provisioning step and the device will always receive commands in an appropriate format